# Maximizing distribution of an object on a mesh surface

Tags: mesh

I'm trying to distribute a large number of shapes onto a mesh surface. I found a command in blender that does this, but it only allows me to place one shape on each vertex/face. I would need to add many more of them.

Is there are a command in blender that will distribute the maximal possible density of a given shape onto the surface area of a spherical mesh?

Comment: You could try a particle system, but how well it will work depends on what you mean by "maximal possible density". Could you elaborate?

Comment: Yes, so basically I am trying to distribute the maximum number of very small pyramids onto the surface of a sphere. So, for example, if I had a surface area of 500 um^2, I would want blender to fit the highest number of tiny pyramids into that surface area that is physically possible without any overlap.

Comment: This sounds like a non-trivial analytic geometry problem.  After you find an algorithm that will compute the placements for these shapes, then I (and any other python coders) can help you turn those placements into blender meshes.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing#Packings_on_the_sphere